# Can't change value in $_SERVER

Tags: nginx, php-7.4

I'm running a PHP app using php-fpm on Docker Windows (Hyper-V).

Inside container I set

```
export MY_VAR=new_value
```

and can confirm it's been set with `printenv`

But on the very first line of my app I get `MY_VAR=old_value` when I do `var_dump($_SERVER['MY_VAR'])`

what am I missing and where did the *old_value* come from?

Comment: Maybe you have env vars inside `/etc/php/7.4/[fpm|cli]/pool.d/*` somewhere?

Comment: @Justinas hey, thanks for the suggestion! was not able to find smth in there